# How to autoload a custom library in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a custom library in my codeigniter application and I need that to be autoloaded. 
Is it possible to do that for custom Libraries?

I tried adding the same in autoload.php, but getting error.

```
Error : Unable to load the requested class: Database,Sessions
```

Sessions.php is my custom library placed inside applications/library package.

```
Code : $autoload['libraries'] = array('database,Sessions');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake in array elements of auto load.

It should be  `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','Sessions');`

Answer (score 0):

It should be like below

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'sessions');
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your file in, `application/libraries` folder and then add your file name in `auto-loader` libraries array element, application/config

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('yourfilname');
```